# MySQL - use WHERE IN clause to JOIN 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, where-clause

I am trying to join 2 tables using `WHERE` and `IN`, instead of `JOIN/LEFT JOIN`.

This is the SQL I wrote which failed when I run it:

```
SELECT 
      product.price as price,
      product.date as date,
      product.status as status,
      a.Title as title
FROM MarketingDb.Product product
WHERE product.Id
IN (
    SELECT a.ListingId, a.Title FROM MarketingDb.Status a
)
LIMIT 15;
```

Error message mentioned: `Unknown column 'a.Title' in 'field list'`

From my understanding, it appears that the error happened because the SQL I wrote only mentioned table `MarketingDb.Status a` inside the subquery, and it's not recognized in the outer SELECT clause.

I would like to ask: how the SQL should be amended such that I can select `a.Title` successfully? Thx a lot for your kind help!

Edit1:

May I ask if instead of just 2 tables, now I wanna join 3rd/4th/... more tables using `IN`, what should be the right way/syntax to do so?

This is what I tried but failed:

```
SELECT 
      product.price as price,
      product.date as date,
      product.status as status,
      (SELECT s.Title FROM MarketingDb.Status s WHERE s.ListingId = product.Id) 
      AS title
FROM MarketingDb.Product product
WHERE product.Id
IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ListingId, a.Title FROM MarketingDb.Status a
)
AND IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT b.Id FROM MArketingDb.Price b
)
LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: (1) Subquery's source table is not visible out of the subquery (2) Where tries to test one column against two columns (3) LIMIT without ORDER BY is a lottery

Comment: Can I suggest NEVER again using IN() to 'join 2 tables'

Comment: @Strawberry Thx for your suggestion. I'm learning and trying to better understand SQL, and I know that `JOIN` should be the better way to achieve the goal of joining tables. I'm just trying to explore more about different MySQL keywords and to see if there are different ways to do the same task. As a result, I can test the performance of different SQL, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this without a join, then use a scalar correlated subquery. Assuming that `status(listingid)` relates to `product(id)`:

```
select 
    p.price,
    p.date,
    p.status,
    (select s.title from marketingdb.status s where s.listingid = p.id) as title
from marketingdb.product p
```

It should be highlighted that this will error if there is more than one row in `status` that matches on a single `product(id)` - if you have such situation, then either limit the number of rows in the subquery... or use a `join`, which allows multiple matches..

Comment: To realize WHERE's filtering action you must at least add `HAVING title IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @GMB thx for your ans! May I ask one more question: instead of just 2 tables, now I wanna use `WHERE` & `IN` to join 3rd, 4th, or even more tables. I was thinking about using `AND` and then followed by another `IN (select...)`, but it turned out to be wrong syntax. May I ask what is the right way to do it? Thx!